# Side Menu BarPosition Error iOS 9

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, swift2

I use the following project to put the side menu in my iOS project. Which can be found [here](https://github.com/jonkykong/SideMenu). When I make click on the bottom to display the menu, it shows me the following error:

> Failed to set (barPosition) user defined inspected property on
>   (UINavigationItem): [ setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not
>   key value coding-compliant for the key barPosition.

Any Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error come from some bad link. Check the identifier if is all set as in your class.